# Aros table in CakePHP is still including Users even after bindNode

Tags: database, cakephp, acl

While following the instructions on the CakePHP book to [create an ACL controlled site](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application), I added the `bindNode` suggested to make it "[Group-Only ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1547/Acts-As-a-Requester#x11-2-4-1-Group-only-ACL-1646)":

```
//in users model
function bindNode($user) {
    return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
}
```

According to [that page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1547/Acts-As-a-Requester#x11-2-4-1-Group-only-ACL-1646), my `aros` table should look like this:

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
| id | parent_id | model | foreign_key | alias | lft  | rght |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | Group |           1 | NULL  |    1 |    2 |
|  2 |      NULL | Group |           2 | NULL  |    3 |    4 |
|  3 |      NULL | Group |           3 | NULL  |    5 |    6 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
```

All is well and good - my group permissions seem to be working correctly...etc, but when users are created, they're still added to the `aros` table.

Is is normal?  Should users be added, just not used for access purposes?  I assumed my table would look just like the example (only groups, no users), so when I started seeing users added, I got concerned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add following line in your User model:

```
public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester', 'enabled' => false));
```

Reference:
http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/1485-bindnode-still-creating-user-model-aros

Answer (score 1):

try changing to

```
function bindNode($user) {
    return array('Group' => array('id' => $user['User']['group_id']));
}
```

and remove

```
function parentNode
```

Comment: Any chance you can explain why I would do it this way instead of the way specified in the Cake Book?  What's different / why does this work and the other doesn't?